# Example of measure for some algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Can you  give an example of a finitely additive measure given on $\mathcal A$, not
having a countably additive extension to a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$ for some algebra $\mathcal A$ over $\mathbb N$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On $\mathbb N$ with the sigma algebra of all subsets let $\mu (A)=0$ if $A$ is a finite set and $\infty$ if it is an infinite set. Then $\mu (\mathbb N)=\infty$ and $\sum _n \mu(\{n\})=0$ so $\mu$ is not countably additive. It is trivial to check that $\mu$ is finitely additive.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me